# FancyBox not displaying html page

Tags: jquery, web, fancybox

So this FancyBox thing is really frustrating me. I have been trying to get it to work for a while now and nothing is happening. When I click on my link all I see is the html file displayed normally in my browser, but no popup or anything.

There is an error saying that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object#<Object> has no method 'fancybox'
```

So in order to fix that I made my link have an ID instead of a class. Now, there are no errors, but nothing happens! I don't even know where to look to fix this. I'll post my code below so if anyone can figure out what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Index.html**

```
    <!-- ******************* CSS ******************* -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <!-- ******************* Javascript ******************* -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.fancybox.pack-1.3.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a.iframe").fancybox({
                'type' : 'iframe'
                'frameWidth':500,
                'frameHeight':500,
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="iframe" href="./iFrameFancy.html">Test FancyBox Here!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML page supposed to load in FancyBox**

```
    <!-- ******************* CSS ******************* -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <!-- ******************* Javascript ******************* -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.fancybox.pack-1.3.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>FancyBox Test!</h1>
    <p>
        This is a test of the FancyBox API. I have no idea if anything is going to work.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did fancybox.css get loaded successfully?  Check chrome developer tools or firebug

Comment: Yes it did. Sorry, changed title of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be working because you have some syntax errors and invalid options here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.iframe").fancybox({
            'type' : 'iframe'
            'frameWidth':500,
            'frameHeight':500,
        });
    });
</script>
```

...so try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.iframe").fancybox({
            'type' : 'iframe',  //<--missing comma here
            'width':500,
            'height':500  //<-- removed last comma here
        });
    });
</script>
```

`frameWidth` and `frameHeight` are for version 1.2.x but you are using v1.3.4.

Also **NOTICE** that in the script above you are binding fancybox to the selector `.iframe`, which means an anchor with `class="iframe"` BUT your html is like:

```
<a id="iframe" href="./iFrameFancy.html">Test FancyBox Here!</a>
```

(no `class` but `ID` there)... when it should be

```
<a class="iframe" href="./iFrameFancy.html">Test FancyBox Here!</a>
```

Additionally make sure that the Fancybox files are loading properly (check your paths) because you are loading the css file from here

```
/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css
```

while the js file from here

```
./jquery.fancybox.pack-1.3.4.js
```

... I wonder if both files are on the same directory or you moved them, otherwise just make sure the fancybox image files are under the same directory as the css file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including jQuery twice? I don't think you need it on the HTML page that you're loading in an iframe. Try removing it.

Comment: it doesn't really matter if fancybox or other scripts are inside the targeted page since it will be opened inside an `iframe` (you could actually have a different version of jQuery or fancybox inside of it)